# Bash - Creating a string with a string variable

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have a variable called CURRENTDATE=20151105.

I want to create a string as below:

abc_20151105_20151105

I tried the following variations:

```
echo "abc_$CURRENTDATE_$CURRENTDATE" 
This gave abc_20151105

echo "abc_'$CURRENTDATE'_'$CURRENTDATE'"
This gave abc_'20151105'_'20151105'
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first version tries to use the `CURRENTDATE_` variable. Use `${CURRENTDATE}_`. The second version does exactly what you'd expect which is expand your variables and leave the single quotes intact.

Comment: As Etan pointed out, the variable name it's first expanding has an underscore appended to it. You can use his suggestion or use \ like so `echo abc_$CURRENT_DATE\_$CURRENT_DATE` I've also found this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88452/concatenating-two-variables-with-an-underscore -- it's worth a read.

Comment: You can even split with quotes. `echo "abc_$CURRENTDATE""_$CURRENTDATE"`. That said, I use curly braces almost whenever possible, to reduce unknowns. I also prefer printf. `printf 'abc_%s_%s\n' "$CURRENTDATE" "$CURRENTDATE"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the underscore is a valid character for a variable name. Try one of these:

```
echo "abc_"$CURRENT_DATE"_"$CURRENT_DATE
echo "abc_${CURRENT_DATE}_$CURRENT_DATE"
```

Bash doesn't have a concatenation operator, so you concatenate strings by smashing them together in the command; this is what the first example is doing. The second uses braces to explicitly point out the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You must surround the variable name with ${} in order to isolate it from other valid characters. Like this:

```
echo "abc_${CURRENT_DATE}_${CURRENT_DATE}"
```